# "Enable Shared Memory" option missing from Virtual Machine Manager

Tags: virtualization, qemu

There's an option in Virtual Machine Manager to share your memory. It's called "Enable shared memory". See #2 below:

[image: Present]

This option is missing in my instance of QEMU under Virtual Machine Manager (Ubuntu 20.04 Host, Windows 11 Guest, virtio-win-guest-tools is installed). How do I make "Enable shared memory" appear?

[image: Missing]